# Can Bash process substitution be used as part of argument expansion?

Tags: bash, command-substitution, process-substitution

I'm familiar with process substitution used the canonical way, e.g.

```
diff <(ls /folder1) <(ls /folder2)
```

However, can it be used when the process asks for an argument that is *not* just the path to the expression? E.g.

```
curl -XPOST https://host:1234/upload -F data=@$(echo <(head -c1M /dev/urandom))
```

This doesn't work because the inner substitution exists for the subshell process, not the outer process; nonetheless, it is effectively what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Isn't `data=@<(head -c1M /dev/urandom)` what you want? (And btw this example wouldn't work because you can't have null bytes in a command argument.)

Comment: @Gilles Ah, I'd used quotes when I tested. Didn't realize <() is parseable mid-string as long as it's not quoted. Thanks! (also, if you post your response as an answer, will mark it)

Comment: @Gilles <() returns a path to a file descriptor, not the data in the pipe, so there wouldn't actually be any NULs in the arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `<(cmd)` syntax what typically happens is the "cmd" is run with stdout connected to a temporary file descriptor, and the file name of that descriptor returned, so it can be used as a parameter

e.g

```
ksh$ echo <(echo hello)
/dev/fd/4

bash$ echo <(echo hello)
/dev/fd/63
```

Now that `/dev/fd/##` entry is only valid in scope for the shell that is calling `<(..)` because `/dev/fd` is a symlink to `/dev/self/fd`.

This means that in your example of `data=@$(echo <(head -c1M /dev/urandom))` if will be parsed as if you'd entered `data=@/dev/fd/63` but that won't work because the shell that is running the `curl` command isn't the shell that had the process subsitution.

Now `<(...)` can be included inside other entries and it will work, as long as you don't pass the temporary filenames around

eg this won't work

```
$ cat <(echo <(echo hello))
/dev/fd/63
```

but this *will* work

```
$ cat <(cat <(echo hello))
hello
```

In your version, though, you have an unnecessary level of indirection and should be able to simply do

```
data=@<(head -c1M /dev/urandom)
```

Comment: Yup, this is basically what I gathered as well. What I was missing here was that <() inside a string works, with the exception of quotes. This is a good overview of the situation, however, so I will accept this. Thanks for the response!